# when i run the project the follwing error occur

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'E:\ecommerce\android\build.gradle' line: 28
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> > 'com.android.build.api.variant.SourceDirectories$Flat com.android.build.api.variant.Sources.getByName(java.lang.String)'

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i delete .gradl folder but still not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.